# Qual a melhor maneira de passar JSON por parâmetro em Angular JS?

Tags: php, angularjs, json

Estou desenvolvendo um sistema usando angular js e php. O usuário insere seu cpf e sua senha em um formulário, lembrando que esse usuário está cadastrado no banco de dados com suas informações, como, endereço, nome, etc. Quando usuário digitar suas credenciais, eu pego esses dados por angular js e repasso ao php usando `$http.post('php/login.php',user);`.

Se o cpf do usuário for encontrado no banco de dados, quero que retorna um `JSON` com todos os dados do usuário e passar por parâmetro usando o `ngRoute` com `$location.path('pagina',+dados_usuarios)`:

```
$http.get('php/login.php', user).success(function(data) {
  var result = JSON.stringify(data, null, 2);
  console.log(result);
  //$location.path('/dashboard/'+result);
}).error(function(data) {
  console.log("Usuário não cadastrado!");
});
```

O PHP está me retornando o json, mas como posso utilizar esse json em outra página em Angular JS ?

Comment: Você está usando o ui-router ou ngRouter?

Comment: Estou usando o ngRouter.

Comment: Veja se te ajuda http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25486392/best-way-to-pass-data-between-ngroute-controllers-from-one-view-to-the-next

Comment: mais tarde posto um fiddle com exemplo ...

Answer (score 1):

Uma das formas de fazer isso é usando *services*.

No seu main.js (onde são declaradas as rotas, controllers e etc) você pode criar um service com um `getter` e um `setter`.

```
app.service('sharedThing', function() {
  var stringValue = '';
  return {
    getString: function() {
      return stringValue;
    },
    setString: function(value) {
      stringValue = value;
    }
  }
});
```

Depois você precisa injetar em todos os controllers em que você ira usar o `service` através de seu identificador `sharedThing`, assim como as outras dependências são injetadas.

```
angular.module('myApp').controller('MyController', function ($scope, $http, $stateParams, sharedThing) { ... });
```

Você pode acessar as funções do `service` da seguinte maneira.

```
sharedThing.setString('Olá Mundo!');
```

ou ainda usar o armazenado como segue:

```
$scope.thing = sharedThing.getString();
```

Ao invés de passar uma string como eu fiz no exemplo, você pode passar objetos, arrays, etc.

---

- [Referência 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20181323/passing-data-between-controllers-in-angular-js)
- [Referência 2](https://www.airpair.com/javascript/posts/services-in-angularjs-simplified-with-examples)
- [Documentação 1](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/services)
- [Documentação 2](http://www.w3schools.com/angular/angular_services.asp)

Answer (score 1):

Assumindo que o seu objeto de usuário é algo assim:

```
{
    "nome": "Roger Barreto",
    "idade": 34,
    "email": "roger@rkti.com",
    "slug": "roger-barreto"
}
```

Alteraria o trecho da sua rotina para:

```
$http.get('php/login.php', user).success(function(response) {
    $location.path('/dashboard/'+ response.data.slug);

 }).error(function(data) {
     console.log("Usuário não cadastrado!");
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

Se você quer guardar esse usuário, e o mesmo não mudar, você pode fazer isso:

**Controller**

```
$http.post("sua url", data).success(function(response) {
     var user = response;
     localStorage.setItem("user", user); //primeiro parâmetro nome desse storage, e o segundo passe seu objeto
})
```

Quando você quiser dar um GET nesse usuário, no seu JS, você faz:

```
var user = localStorage.getItem("user");
```

Caso você queria alterar esse usuário, basta remover esse localStorage, e criar outro passando o objeto atualizado, assim:

```
$http.put("sua url", data).success(function(response){
    var user = response;
    localStorage.removeItem("user"); //user é o local storage que já existe
    localStorage.setItem("user", user);
})
```

Essa não é a melhor solução, mas é uma delas... Você pode fazer, como o pmargreff falou, um serviço com gets e sets, ou um model. Você também pode passar o seu objeto user através do $state.go....